# Why is Godzilla hunting after the MUTOs?

Tags: godzilla, godzilla-2014, monsterverse

In Godzilla (2014 Film) why is Godzilla hunting the MUTOs in the first place?

Comment: I vaguely recall a comment about Gozilla being an alpha predator and just being territorial.

Comment: @phantom42 -Also I vaguely remember some comment about him finding their calls *annoying*.

Comment: There was a whole story line about how the MUTOs and Godzilla were natural enemies, as evidenced by finding a dead (much larger) Godzilla that had been killed by MUTOs some millenia (or whatever) ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUTO_(Godzilla)) (which itself cites the book ***Godzilla: Art of Destruction***):

> David Callaham's first draft featured early versions of the MUTOs
>   where they were established as ancient enemies of Godzilla but never
>   established as to why. When director Edwards came aboard the project,
>   he created a back story to bridge the gap between Godzilla's
>   connection with the MUTOs. Edwards brainstormed the idea that, "When
>   these Godzillas were on Earth, there was another creature that would
>   kill them and lay its eggs inside their dead bodies. Therefore, if
>   these creatures ever came back, part of their life cycle would be the
>   ability to attract Godzillas to the surface to kill them for
>   reproduction."

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Godzilla hunted the mutos because of natural behavior, if we look at king of the monsters, Monster Zero was becoming the alpha of all the titans, so Godzilla set things right and killed Monster Zero, this made it so that he was the alpha. we see this again in Godzilla vs Kong, were Godzilla has to "kill" Mecha Godzilla because he was sending off signals saying "hey, I'm the new alpha now." leading to MechaGodzillas death, in Godzilla 2014, The MUTOs were threatening Godzilla's supremacy, so he killed them so that they would not do it again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   This seems to be a retcon, and not the originally envisioned reason?

Comment: @DavidW If it's the canon reason as of the latest films, then does it matter whether it's a retcon or not? There's plenty of precedent for questions about one film to be answered using material from its sequel(s), *Star Wars* being an obvious one.

Comment: @F1Krazy Maybe I just get a bit squirrelly about retcons, but the original creator stated a perfectly cromulent reason that made a lot more sense.  It's also not clear if the MUTOs threatening to be alpha is an official retcon or just headcanon, especially since the MUTOs were obviously not a match for Godzilla in a one-on-one fight.